# If I want to change the route in a test controllers file, do I have to edit any other files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, railstutorial.org

I want to change the route in this file from **users_new_url** to **signup_path**:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get new" do
    get users_new_url
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

I have tried simply replacing it,

```
get signup_path
```

but when I run rails test, it always says that *signup_path* is an "undefined local variable or method". Do I need to edit other files?

If it helps, the following code is from test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb.

Update: I updated my `routes.rb` file with `get 'signup', to: 'users#new'`.

Comment: Yes, you need to modify your `routes.rb` and setup a named route `signup` in order for it to be available in your application, including tests. Please update your question and include the contents of your `routes.rb`. Or you could review http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers to understand how the named route helpers work.

Comment: @Dharam, I updated my `routes.rb` file with `get 'signup', to: 'users#new'` and ran a successful rails test.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to modify your `routes.rb` and setup a named route signup in order for it to be available in your application, including tests. You could review [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers) to understand how the named route helpers work.